# React, почему внутри функции при проверке состояния всегда показывает изначальное состояние (не обновляется)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Внутри функции при проверке состояния всегда показывает изначальное состояние (не обновляется)

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
const [pages, setPages] = useState(0)
const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true)


  useEffect(()=>{
    if(fetching){
      fetch(`https://someserver/pages=${currentPage}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        setPages(json.totalPages)
        setFilms([...data, ...json.data])
        setCurrentPage(prevState => prevState + 1)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      .finally(()=> setFetching(false))
    }
  }, [fetching])


  useEffect(() =>{
    document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    return function (){
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    }
  }, [])


const scrollHandler = (e) => {
  if((e.target.documentElement.scrollHeight - (e.target.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) < 100) && 
  (currentPage != pages)){
    setFetching(true)
\\Здесь выводит всегда изначальное состояние
    console.log(pages) // 0 
    console.log(currentPage) // 1
  }
}

\\А здесь все нормально, как и должно быть
console.log(pages) // 16
console.log(currentPage) // 2
```

Comment: Если использовать useRef() то работает

Comment: Попробуйте scrollHandler обернуть хуком useCallback, добавить все необходимые зависимости и в useEffect добавить зависимость scrollHandler